# SWRevealViewController Issue while getting currentController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used the following method to get the current `viewController` but it always returns `SWRevealViewController` as currentController.

I have used `SWRevealViewController` for handling a slide menu.

```
extension UIApplication {
  class func topViewController(base: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController!)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
  }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to get the current controller:

```
 let topVC = UIApplication.topViewController(((UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController)!)
    print(topVC)
    if topVC!.isKindOfClass(mycontroller) == false{
        //do something
    }else{
     // do another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saroj, did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue on SWRevealViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching current view controller like this:

```
   UIViewController *topController = self.window.rootViewController;
     while (topController.presentedViewController) {
     topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
```